# vue 2 lifecycle - how to stop beforeDestroy?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Can I add something to `beforeDestroy` to prevent destroying the component? ?

Or is there any way to prevent destroying the component ?

my case is that when I change spa page by vue-route, I use watch route first, but I found that doesn't trigger because the component just destroy..

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to make, but have you check the `keep-alive` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#keep-alive ?

Comment: I mean.. my app's component doesn't use keep-alive, how to prevent destroy component when vue route change? (I think watch route first, but I found that doesn't trigger because the component just destroy)

Answer (score 6):

As **belmin bedak** commented you can use `keep-alive`

- when you use  `keep-alive` two more lifecycle hooks come into action, they are `activated` and `deactivated` hooks instead of `destroyed`
- The purpose of  `keep-alive` is to cache and to not destroy the  component
- you can use `include` and `exclude` atteibutes of the  `keep-alive` element and mention the names of the components that shoulb be included to be cached and be excluded from caching. Here is [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive)
- in case you want to forecefully destroy the component even if its cached you can use `vm.$destroy()` [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-destroy)

Further you can `console.log` in all the lifecycle hooks and check which lifecycle hook is being called

Answer (score 4):

You can use vue-route [navigation-guards](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html), so if you call `next(false)` inside the hook, navigation will be aborted.

```
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  if(your condition){
    next(false) //this will abort route navigation
  }
})
```

Comment: You must use "beforeEach" instead of "afterEach" because "afterEach" does not work in such way. You may check my answer in this question.

Comment: According to the same source you showed: afterEach does "not get a next( ) function and cannot affect the navigation". Naturally, JavaScript throws an error: "TypeError: next is not a function"

Answer (score 2):

According to this source: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

I suggest you to do something like this with your Vue router:

```
const router = new VueRouter({  }); // declare your router with params

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if(yourCondition){
        next(false); // prevent user from navigating somewhere
    } else {
        return next(); // navigate to next "page" as usual
    }
});
```

This will prevent destroying your Vue instance on your declared condition, and it will also prevent user from navigating to another page.

Answer (score 1):

Although I would consider @Vamsi Krishna "keep-alive" answer to be the proper "VueJS way" to solve this issue, I was not willing to refactor part of my code for it.

I also couldn't use the Vue router navigation guard "as-is" because in the case of `beforeRouterLeave`, even though using `next(false)` prevented the route from continuing, the component in Vue was ALREADY destroyed. Any state I had that wasn't saved would be lost, which defeats the purpose of cancelling the route change.

This wasn't what I wanted, as I needed the state of the form/settings in the component to remain (the component reloaded itself and kept the same route).

So I came up with a strategy that still used a navigation guard, but also cached any form changes/settings I had in the component in-memory, eg. I add a beforeRouteLeave hook in the component:

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
  if (!this.isFormDirty() || confirm('Discard changes made?')) {
    _cachedComponentData = null // delete the cached data
    next()
  } else {
    _cachedComponentData = this.componentData // store the cached data based on component data you are setting during use of the component
    next(false)
  }
}
```

Outside the Vue component, I initialize `_cachedComponentData`

```
<script>
let _cachedComponentData = null
module.exports = {
  ...component code here
}
<script>
```

Then in the `created` or `mounted` life cycle hooks, I can set the `_cachedComponentData` to "continue where the user left off" in the component:

```
...
if (_cachedComponentData) {
  this.componentData = _cachedComponentData
}
...
```