# Prevent page from downloading files every time it's accessed

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an animation inside my Vue.js app, that is displayed in one page of the application. Every time I visit the page the assets for the animation get re-downloaded from the beginning. The application does get `destroyed` when I leave the page. And one way to achieve this is to use `v-show` instead of `v-if`, which would not destroy it, however that gives other issues for my use case, because this way the animation gets loaded as soon as the main page is loaded, which I do now want.

Is there a way in JS to help with this problem?

The application is also a `PWA` and I have a `service-worker` working, is there any way that could be used to my advantage in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Vue provides a `transition` wrapper component, allowing you to add entering/leaving transitions for any element or component:

- Conditional rendering (using `v-if`).
- Conditional display (using `v-show`).

That's mean `v-show` loading the assets but not showing other than `v-if`. Also, the `transition` will apply on both when you conditions activated. Here a live [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-shape-9ft27?file=/src/App.vue).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in case anyone else has the same problem.

Vue provides a  `keep-alive` tag, which caches the element and does not destroy it. And so my assets do not get re-downloaded each time even if I use `v-if` .

Some more details on this question [vue 2 lifecycle - how to stop beforeDestroy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43449747/vue-2-lifecycle-how-to-stop-beforedestroy)